# Generic validator with database access in nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, decorator

I have created a custom validator which aims to check that a value does not already exist for an entity and a given field.

At the beginning, I was going to inject directly in my validator the entity I need, but I don't like this solution, because it forces me to create a validator for each field/entity to check.

I decided to use the following solution: use my database connection to use the type orm query builder. This way I can inject, via the decorator options, the name of the entity I want to touch and "voilà" my validator is generic.

Except that, ..., I can't find how to inject my connection to my database and in fact, I don't even know if this is a good idea.

Does this make sense to you? How can I do it?

---

Currently, my code looks like this:

Validator file :

```js
import {
  ValidatorConstraint,
  type ValidatorConstraintInterface,
  type ValidationArguments,
  type ValidationOptions, registerDecorator
} from 'class-validator';
import { Connection } from 'mysql2';

/**
 * register the decorator
 * @param {string} entityName the name of the entity where you want to perform the uniqueness check
 * @param {ValidationOptions} validationOptions the options you want to pass to the validator
 * @returns {void}
 */
export function IsUnique(entityName: string, validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  return (object: object, propertyName: string): void => {
    registerDecorator({
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName,
      options: validationOptions,
      constraints: [entityName],
      validator: IsUniqueClass
    });
  };
}

// named IsUnique*Class* because I want to use @IsUnique for my decorator name setup above
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'isUnique', async: true })
export class IsUniqueClass implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  constructor(private readonly connection: Connection) {}

  /**
   * check that the given value is unique for the given field and table
   * @param {unknown} value the tested value
   * @param {ValidationArguments} args the arguments of the demand injected via the decorator
   * @returns {boolean} if the value is unique or not
   */
  async validate(value: unknown, args: ValidationArguments): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log('validator args >>>>>>>>>> ', { value, args });
    const repo: string = args.constraints[0];
    // obviously connection is undefined here
    const r = this.connection.query(`select * from ${repo}`);
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * error message if the validation failed
   * @param {ValidationArguments} args the arguments of the demand injected via the decorator
   * @returns {string} the error message
   */
  defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments): string {
    const { value } = args;
    return `The value '${value as string}' already exist`;
  }
}
```

And I use it like this (in a DTO) :

```js
export class CreateExerciseTypeDto {
  /* identity data */
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @IsUnique(ExerciseType) // just here my custom validator
  name: string;
}
```

My DB connection is done in the app module like the docs say :

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: '',
      database: 'databaseName',
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
      logging: ['error']
    }),
    TrainingModule,
    ExerciseModule,
    ExerciseTypeModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still looking for answer or not but I solved this issue by injecting **DataSource** instead of **Connection** and then use it like this

```
const queryRunner = this.dataSource.createQueryRunner();
const result = await queryRunner.query(query);
```

Hope it helps someone